# Sublime returning binary looking text from semi-plain text

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, quicklook

Examining some files (log files, *.ldb files which are backups created by a chrome extension and so on) I find that some of those files are seen OK by Mac's QuickLook:

[image: QuickLook]

---

But sublime open them like this:

[image: Sublime 3]

---

Explanations? Fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ST3's default preferences is the following:

```
// Files containing null bytes are opened as hexadecimal by default
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": true,
```

so I guess your `ldb` files contain null bytes. Simply set this to `false` in your user preferences, and ST should try to display the file as text.

Comment: Thanks. In ST3 a temporal fix is to File -> Reopen with Encoding -> UTF-8